# Problem with the solution of a third degree equation

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

**Problem:** If $m \ n$ and $1$ are the solution to the equation $x^3-mx^2+nx-1$, find their sum $(m+n+1)$.

Here's how I tried to solve it:

If a solution is $x=m$ then if I substitute the $x$ in the equation I get
$$m^3-m^3+mn-1=0 \rightarrow mn=1$$ 
If $x=1$
$$1-m+n-1=0 \rightarrow m=n$$

So we have
$$mn=1 ; m=n$$
$$m=1 \wedge n=1 \bigvee m=-1  \wedge n=-1$$
So $m+n+1= 3 \vee m+n+1=-1$

Is this correct?

Comment: By expanding you see that
$$(x-1)(x-m)(x-n)=x^3-(m+n+1)x^2+\cdots,$$ so by looking at the quadratic terms you get a further relation $m+n+1=m$. What can you deduce from that?

Comment: if $m+n+1=m$ then $n=-1$ and follows from my demonstration that also $m=-1$; also $m+n+1=-1$ correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of interpretation.

If $m,n,1$ must be the three solutions in the sense that there is no other solution, then $m=n=-1$ is the only valid choice.

If we only require $f(n)=f(m)=f(1)=0$, then $m=n=1$ is another valid choice (with $\pm i$ being the other two roots of the polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

The equation must equal $(x-1)(x-m)(x-n)$, so multiply $(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)$ and $(x-1)(x+1)(x+1)$ to check.